# Copying text to clipboard removes text from textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clipboard

I have been having trouble copying text from a rich text box to the windows clipboard in a C# windows application. Using the following code results in the selected text being deleted, and also not copied to the clipboard:

```
Clipboard.SetText(Input_Box.SelectedText);
```

Using:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(Input_Box.SelectedText);
```

produced the same result.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you will need to provide some more details around your code, because I just created a simple application with a rich text box and used the `SetText` method you mentioned above and all worked perfectly (I had to select the text first of course).

Comment: You can just call [`Input_Box.Copy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.copy.aspx), of course..

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder: You need to go try that code out before you post more.

Answer (score 0):

I think If you need to copy entire text in the rich textbox to clipboard you may try this..

```
Clipboard.SetText(Input_Box.Text);
```

If you need to copy some selected text to clip board you can use

```
Clipboard.SetText(Input_Box.SelectedText);
```

And if you try the second one you may need to select some text from the textbox before copy.Otherwise you may get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

In Winforms:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(...)
```

In WPF:

```
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(...)
```